# how to disable user to go back after login in flutter

Tags: android, ios, flutter, navigation, navigator

In this app when user click login page is navigate to homepage but when user press back button on home screen then page is navigate to login so this is not a right flow

I triend navigator.pushReplacement but when user press back button while on home screen app is close and go to background and when user open that app from background then instead showing home screen it show login screen so please give suggestions,

Here is my code
LoginScreen

```
Future<void> login(
      String emailId, String password, String accessToken) async {
    final dio = Dio(); // Provide a dio instance
    String token = AppStrings.keyBearer + accessToken;
    var customHeaders = {
      AppStrings.authorization: token,
      AppStrings.keyContentType: AppStrings.valueContentType
    };

    dio.options.headers.addAll(customHeaders);
    final client = RestClient(dio);
    await client
        .loginUser(LoginUser(
            deviceToken: AppStrings.valueDeviceToken,
            lastLoginPlatform: AppStrings.valuePlatform))
        .then((res) {
          if(res.interests.isEmpty){
            AppHelper.showToastMessage(
                AppStrings.message_logged_in_successfully);
            Navigator.of(context, rootNavigator: true).pop();
            Navigator.push(
                context,
                MaterialPageRoute(
                    builder: (context) => InterestsPage(
                      userAccesstoken: accessToken,
                    )));
          }
          else{
            AppHelper.showToastMessage(
                AppStrings.message_logged_in_successfully);
            Navigator.of(context, rootNavigator: true).pop();
            Navigator.push(
                context,
                MaterialPageRoute(
                    builder: (context) =>  HomePage(
                      userAccesstoken: accessToken,
                      userInterests: res.interests
                    )));
          }
    }).catchError((Object obj) {
      switch (obj.runtimeType) {
        case DioError:
          final res = (obj as DioError).response;
          Navigator.of(context, rootNavigator: true).pop();
          logger.e(res.statusMessage);
          AppHelper.showToastMessage(AppStrings.message_something_went_wrong);
          break;
      }
    });
  }
```

I used

```
Navigator.of(context, rootNavigator: true).pop();
```

for close dialog box

I don't get any error but I want when user press back button on home screen app goes background and when user open that app from background show home screen not login screen

Show me where I made mistake in navigation and how to resolve it.

Comment: Hi you have to save the value in session when you login success full and check it on splash screen every time, If user is login then open Home page otherwise open login

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The method you are looking for is `pushReplacement`, and the way to go is:

```dart
Navigator.of(context).pop();
Navigator
  .of(context)
  .pushReplacement(
    MaterialPageRoute(
      builder: (BuildContext context) => InterestsPage(
    userAccesstoken: accessToken,
    )
  )
)
```

This way, it will pop out of the alert message, and then replace all the previous pages with the one that you want.

However, the logic behing wether the login page needs to be displayed comes down to preference, and since I can't say how to do it without addicional code. I, for example, store the user on a local database after login. This way, even without a connection, there is a way to access the app.

Answer (score -1):

You should use routes on your main file, using PushReplacement just works great there is no problem with it, you should decide where to navigate the user base on if the user logged in before or not, you can use something like [share preferences](https://pub.dev/packages/shared_preferences) to achieve this functionality. after login just save a pref that says user logged in and then on your splash screen navigate the user to correct screen

Comment: There is no need to do that, since you can replace the previous routes after validating the login.

Comment: @AntónioOliveira then how do you decide where to navigate on after app closed?

Comment: Shared preferences should not be used to persist information. You can use it for temporary information, but you should only use it during runtime. For his case, persisting information about the user needs to be somewhat more permanent, therefore having a well structured local database for those kinds of checks is recommended. It's fine for some information, but after some time, it gets confusing. Furthermore, he is not using routes, so the best solution is not to implement an alternative for what he has.